# Encountering errors when rsync files to a NAS via ssh

Tags: linux, rsync, centos6, nas

Hi everyone on Stack Overflow,

I am attempting to rsync files from a specific folder of my CentOS 6.7 server to a EMS5 NAS 3000-SRL16. I tried the following code:

```
rsync -av -e ssh /bml/Data/ admin@IP address::BMLab
```

/bml/Data/ is the folder needs backing up, and I have a folder called BMLab in the NAS. The IP address of the NAS is typed in "IP address" above.

However, error messages showed up. I'm pasting them below:

> rsync: server sent "Welcome to cliadm 1.0 build:$Revision: 173 $" rather than greeting
>   rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1503) [sender=3.0.6]

I don't have any previous experience regarding rsync, and I really have no idea of what's going on here, not to mention that how to solve it.

Any response is much appreciated.

Comment: You could try `--debug=connect,cmd` and see if there are any clues there. The problem would appear to be how your NAS responds to connection.

Comment: It seems like that the NAS simply can't communicate with our server via ssh rsync. We mounted the NAS to our server with network connection, and then rsync works just fine.